# Tramp doesn't trash remote directories

Tags: tramp

When I try to trash a remote directory, either through `dired` or with `delete-directory`, Tramp just deletes it.  If I try to trash a remote file, it does trash it properly.

I have `delete-by-moving-to-trash` set to `t`.  If I call `tramp-get-remote-trash` for my remote host, it returns `"\\trash"`.

I've been stepping through the calls, and it ends up calling `tramp-sh-handle-delete-directory`, which doesn't seem to have a trash option.  I wonder if things aren't going wrong in `delete-directory`, where the `cond` clauses are ordered such that the file name handler is found and called without a trash argument before the clause which handles trashing a directory.  But I might not yet understand this code properly.

Does anyone know how to get Tramp to trash a remote directory properly?

Comment: I would file a bug report: worst case you've missed some obscure setting in `tramp`, which may be a bug in itself.

Comment: @wvxvw OK, thanks.  I just submitted a bug report.  I'll create an answer here once it gets resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related Emacs bug [26763](https://debbugs.gnu.org/26763) has been fixed in the repository. Fix will appear with next Emacs 26.1.